# go module dependency another local directory

Tags: go

I have the following folders:

```
folder1:
   go.sum
   go.mod
   main.go

folder2:
   proto.pb.go
```

How in folder1 can I add the proto.pb.go as a dependency, so that files in folder1 can access to proto.pb.go?

Comment: You cannot depend on "files" in Go. You can only depend on packages.

Comment: Use the `replace` directive in `go.mod`.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant for package, not files. How can I depend on another package in some other folder? We do want to keep the go.sum and go.mod under folder1. we can also create a go.mod under folder2. but we don't want to create a go.mod in one folder above them.